# Chainlink Node: job type 'webhook' has not been registered with the job.Spawner

Tags: toml, chainlink

I have a `toml` job spec that looks like:

```
type            = "webhook"
schemaVersion   = 1
observationSource   = """
    send_to_bridge [type=bridge name="vesper-test" requestData="{\\"data\\": {\\"quote\\":\\"USD\\"}}"]
    send_to_bridge
"""
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
job type 'webhook' has not been registered with the job.Spawner
```

How do I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `FEATURE_WEBHOOK_V2=true` in your `.env`